# Let $G$ be a group generated by two involutions $x$ and $y$. Show that there is some $N\unlhd G$ with $[G:N]=2$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, involutions

This is **Exercise 3.35** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*. According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgroup-theory%5D+generated+by+two+involutions+normal+subgroup+of+index+two), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

**Presentations are not covered in the book so far**, so, presumably, there is a way to answer it without thinking of $G$ given by (some quotient of) the free product

$$\Bbb Z_2\ast\Bbb Z_2\cong \langle x,y\mid x^2,y^2\rangle.$$

The [combinatorial-group-theory](/questions/tagged/combinatorial-group-theory) tag **does not apply**.

Since I sometimes get involutions and idempotents mixed up, here is a

> **Definition:** An element $f$ of a group $G$ with identity $e$ is an *involution* if $f^2=e$.

Since there is a plethora of definitions for a normal subgroup, the following is from the book cited above.

> **Definition 2:** A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is *normal* in $G$, written $H\unlhd G$, if $$aH=Ha$$ for all $a\in G$.

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be a group generated by two involutions $x$ and $y$. Show that $G$ has a normal subgroup of index two.

### Thoughts:

It won't help to consider, without loss of generality, that the normal subgroup - let's call it $N$ - is $\langle x\rangle$, say, since, although $x\langle x\rangle=\langle x\rangle x$, trivially, the same cannot be said in general for $y\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle x\rangle y$.

It does give me the idea, though, that, to test the normality of $N$ in $G$, we need only show that $xN=Nx$ and $yN=Ny$.

Exactly where the $[G:N]=2$ comes from is a mystery to me. My hope is that some pithy choice of generators for $N$ would work, but, well, that's using techniques not yet covered in the book.

I feel like this is a question I ought to be able to answer myself. I've given it a few days and this is all I have.

Please help :)

Comment: what about if we define $\phi:G\to \{e,x\}$ with $\phi(y)=e,\;\phi(x0=x$. then put n the kernel of this morphism?

Comment: @AliTaghavi You seem to assume that $G$ is *freely* generated by $x$ and $y$, so that you can define $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ arbitrarily and get a group homomorphism.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for your comment. Is not the homorphism I defined a well defined homomorphism on the quotient of free group sibject to relation x^2=y^2=e? I think it is well defined by consideration of  reduced version of words. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @AndreasBlass  I add an answer which shows that such a $\phi$ is legal.

Comment: With a fundamental group point of view your questions can be  widly generalized(in an appropriate manner) to arbitrary generatores and arbitrary relations(more general than$ x^2=y^2=e$. Please see the process ofproof of the theorem in Allen Hatcher books iwhich says "every group is the fundamental group of a topological space:

Comment: Moreover this algebraic topological consideration simplifies pure algebraic solutions for such kind of problems

Comment: @AliTaghavi: The point that Shaun makes, however, is that since presentations of groups have not been covered yet, that kind of machinery is not available and not expected to be used to solve the problem. You are bringing in a cannon when it was specifically said that no firearms should be brought to bear.

Comment: @Shaun: One way to get to the point where my answer might suggest itself is to think about how elements of $G$ might look like; arbitrary products of $x$ and $y$ will end up being of the form $(xy)^k$, $y(xy)^k$, or $(xy)^kx$, since any consecutive $x$s and $y$s will cancel out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $\langle xy\rangle$. Note that $(xy)^{-1}=yx$. Therefore, $x(xy)x^{-1} = xxyx = yx = (xy)^{-1}\in\langle xy\rangle$, and $y(xy)y^{-1} = y(xy)y = yx = (xy)^{-1}\in\langle xy\rangle$. Thus, $\langle xy\rangle$ is normal. Call it $N$.

Now note that $G/N$ is abelian, since $[x,y]=xyxy\in N$ and $G/N$ is generated by $xN$ and $yN$. On the other hand, if $x\in N$ then there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=(xy)^n$, and since $x$ has order $2$ we may assume $n\gt 0$. Pick $n$ minimal with this property. Then $x=x(yx)^{n-1}y$, so $(yx)^{n-1}y=e$. Therefore $(yx)^{n-1}=y$, so $y(xy)^{n-2}x = y$. Therefore, $(xy)^{n-2} = x$. By the minimality of $n$, either $n=1$ or $n=2$. If $n=1$, then $y=(yx)^0=e$, which contradicts the assumption that $y$ has order $2$. Therefore, $n=2$. But then $yx
=y$, so $x=e$, again a contradiction. Thus $x\notin N$. Symmetrically, $y\notin N$. Thus, $G/N$ is abelian, nontrivial, generated by two elements of order $2$. But since $xN=yN$ (as $y=xxy\in xN$), $G/N$ is cyclic of order $2$. So $N$ will work.

Comment: +1 for your interesting answer. I think the subgroup $N$ you constructed is the kernel of $\psi:G\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with $\psi(x)=\psi(y)=1$. It is actualy the induced map $g_{*}$ on corresponding fundamental group for $g:\mathbb{R}P^2\vee \mathbb{R}P^2\to \mathbb{R}P^2$ with $g=id$ on each part of the wedge sum.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I know about free products and presentations. The problem specifically asks to not use that. You also unwarrantedly assume the group is presented by $x^2=y^2=e$ and no other relations; you don’t know that.  You would need to argue that your map $g$ factors through $G$ to give you $\psi$, and do so without the benefit of von Dyck’s theorem or the theory of presentations. We all have nuclear weapons in our pockets to solve problems. But when you are asked to participate in an archery contest, don’t bring a machine gun (and on top of that, ignore the difficult issues about using it)

Comment: You are right that I did not pay attention to the fact that $x^2=y^2=e$ is not necessarily all existing relation. may be we have some other presentation formula. thank you for informing me of my mistake in this regard. But I still think that a possible algebraic topological argument would be interesting to solve such kind of problems. I think that interfaces between pure algebraic subjects and intuitional objects  are always interesting.

Comment: sorry I  did not pay attention to the first part of the question too"He does not like use presentation since it is is not cover by the book". after all you are right my annswer is wrong but i do not delete it since there are some comments on my answer so I respect their effort.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Just as a suggestion: perhaps next time read the question before answering it?

Comment: A reasonable suggestion. Thanks. BTW what about higher number of generators which are involutions as well?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}P^2\vee \mathbb{R}P^2$ be the wedge sum of two copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Consider the continuous function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}P^2$ which is identity on one copy and is constant on the other copy. Then $$f_{*}:G=\pi_1(X)\to \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $$ is a surjective homomorphism whose kernel is a subgroup of index $2$.

**Remark:** This homomorphism is actually the homomorphism $\phi$ which is presented in the comment to OP post.

Comment: As far as I can see, you're assuming that the relations $x^2=y^2=e$ are the *only* relations needed to specify the group, i.e., that $G$ is the free product of two copies of $\mathbb Z/2$.  But all we're given in the question is that $G$ is some quotient of that free product.

Comment: You assert that $G$ is $\pi_1(X)$. There is no justification for that assertion. For all you know, $G$ is a finite dihedral group. All you know is that it is generated by two involutions. You would need to argue that your map *factors through* $G$. Right now, the argument is incorrect for the problem at hand.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  Thank you very much for your kind comments and helping me to realize my mistake. may be I was confusing with amalgamation of groups. Now the beauty of the problem posts by OP is more clear to me.Just a question: Do you think that the same arguments discussed on this post can  be easilly generalized to higher number of involutive generators?

Comment: @AndreasBlass  Just another question:Are not some universal properties: That is the G in the question is a morphism image of the group i was talking about? Then what would be happen if we sand the N i talked about into G?